# how to add @ in route in nuxtjs. e.g: example.com/@username

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxtjs

I have been searching to how to add a **@** in dynamic route in nuxtjs.

I want to achieve **example.com/@username**

I have tried to create a directory named **'@'** and inside it i created a file **_user.vue** but that leads to **@/username**

I have also tried to extend router in config and create a custom route like

```
router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        name: 'user',
        path: '/(@):username',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/userProfile.vue')
      })
    }
  },
```

but nuxt is preventing it & throwing error:

```
Expected "0" to match "@", but received "%40"
```

What i understand with this, is, it is url-encoding the **@** sign and **username**.

how do i achieve my desired output, (it is possible in vue router) as discussed in this below issue

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/499

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nvm.

I have just fixed it myself. posting answer to help others;

Nuxt doesnt support **@_username.vue** route name in nuxt filesystem routing.
to achieve route as **example.com/@username** we need to extend it in nuxt.config.js file in router object and define our custom route as

```
router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        name: 'user',
        path: '/@:username',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/userProfile.vue')
      })
    }
  },
```

defination of route is exactly same as vue router, as nuxt implements vue router.
so here,

**name** property is route name

**path** property is route path (prv. i was trying it (@):username which was leading to error, & it just got fixed when i removed brackets)

**component** property is page/component file name and it can exist anywhere, just set the file path where it exists.

Thanks me later!
cheers